# Mount HTTP Serverlocally

Tags: linux, mount, http

i have a HTTP server in windows machine.so i want to mount that to my Linux machine locally.Is that possible.How we can do that.We can mount FTP using curlftpfs.Is there any thing for HTTP.I am using SSHFS which works fine. But for Windows systems, or systems without SSH we cant use that
When i Google i saw davfs2.I try to use that.But i cant find out the correct usage.So any one can help me regarding this?Any help would be appreciable

Comment: DAV is the only way this is ever going to work (somewhat) reliably.

Comment: how we can use that.any idea or any example

Comment: we need to do some configuration on server side for this ?